# laravel Auth::guard()->attempt() not working

Tags: laravel

I am having a problem getting past this line of code in order to authenticate users

```
if(Auth::guard('general')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember'))){
}
```

All lines inside it is not been reached, but
if i remove the attempt section it goes through e.g.

```
if(Auth::guard('general')){
}
```

I do not know what going on. could be that

Comment: `Auth::guard('general')` to `Auth::guard('general')->check()` use this

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry for not replying early. I had found a different route for the problem

Comment: then post new question